# Using Visual Studio 2019 convert Android keystore to the pem format

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, keystore, pem

I created a keystore for my Android app.  Now I need to convert the myapp.keystore file to the pem file format.  Does anyone know how to do that?

(The previous developer is unable to find the key and we need to submit a new key to google play console.  the google tech support gave us instructions but they require using the Android Studio app.)

Comment: the tools to do this are part of the Android SDK, not Visual Studio

Comment: keytool is actually part of the Java SDK. You can find it on Windows in: `C:\Program Files\Android\Jdk\microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25\bin\keytool.exe` or on macOS in: `~/Library/Developer/Xamarin/jdk/microsoft_dist_openjdk_1.8.0.25/bin/keytool`